# Cross browser Selecting elements by class name

Tags: javascript

How do I select all elements using same class name in javascript. I know i can do it using `document.getElementsByClassName` but I read somewhere that it's not cross browser so if it is true what is the appropriate way to select elements depending on class name without jQuery or other library.

Thanks!

Comment: Believe me when I say you are not the first person to ask this question... http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=select+by+class+name+javascript

Comment: @Raj give [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll) a try, it's better and more flexible than `getElement...()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found this code:

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(classname) {
        var elArray = [];
        var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classname + "(\\s|$)");
        for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {

            if (regex.test(tmp[i].className)) {
                elArray.push(tmp[i]);
            }
        }

        return elArray;
    };
}​
```

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149557/601179)

Answer (score 1):

see here:

[Support for getElementsByClassName](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElementsByClassName)

I recommend using [querySelector](http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelector). It's more natural  and pretty close to the jQuery Syntax, thus more common to most ppl. Also it's pretty fast and you don't need to distinguish between classes, ids or whatever.

If you want to Support IE<7, you need a shim like gdoron provided.

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to use document.querySelector or document.querySelectorAll, supported since IE8.

Have a look here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll