# How to get contents of class through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I need to use JavaScript to get the username which is posted in the following way:

```
<div id="project_user">
    <p class="project_user">
        by <span class="project_username"><?php echo $OwnerName; ?></span>
     </p>
</div>
```

How do I do it?

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
document.getElementById('project_username').innerHTML
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You select by `id` while you need to select by the `className`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('project_username')[0].innerHTML
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QVq9z/1/)

Note that `document.getElementsByClassName` is not implemented in old IE versions...

---

Another way:

```
document.getElementById('project_user')
        .getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
```

**[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QVq9z/)**

---

You can use this "patch" to define this function in old browsers:

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {
    document.getElementsByClassName = function(classname) {
        var elArray = [];
        var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
        var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classname + "(\\s|$)");
        for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
            if (regex.test(tmp[i].className))
                elArray.push(tmp[i]);
        }

        return elArray;
    };
}​
```

[**source**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149557/601179)

---

Or use a javascript library like `jQuery` that implements (almost) all css selectors, example:

```
$('.project_username').html();
```

Comment: Thanks so much to everyone. I have gone the perhaps lazy route, and have added jQuery, working very nicely.

Comment: @Jashwant. I think a good programmer is a workaround programmer... And when you're a javascript developer, you need to have plenty of those... `:)`

Comment: Right. And when you are css developer, you start believing in GOD. (`clear cache`....`refresh`....plz god this should work.....on God, not again `:D`)

Comment: I tried to do it using IE, and open https://security.googleblog.com/2015/09/https-support-coming-to-blogspot.html.

I do inspect element and want to show the alert with its value.
alert(document.getElementsByClassName('post-header')[0].innerHTML);

But nothing happened. can you tell me why?

Comment: @RaspiSurya can you create a jsfiddle with the problem?

Comment: I want to right click context menu at IE, and click the menu to execute the script. The script is to access the current url that opened in IE and get the class name of its website, It is possible?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48973126/contextmenu-in-ie-to-get-the-current-opened-browser-url?noredirect=1#comment84951570_48973126
@gdoron that is what I want to do

Answer (score 1):

#### Which Browser Supports Which Method(s)?

`document.getElementById` only works when the element has `id='targetvalue'`. Your example above shows the value being in the `class` attribute, rather than the `id`.

You could use `getElementsByClassName`, though this isn't supported in IE8 or lower. There's also `document.querySelectorAll`, which has slightly better support in IE.

#### Mmm, Browser Support-Charts are Pretty

You can check the browser support for various methods of getting elements online at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#gettingelements.

#### The Verbosity of Doing it Alone

Making a broad cross-browser compatible solution could be verbose:

```
var parent = document.getElementById("project_user"),
    element;

// If the browser supports querySelectorAll, use it.
if ( parent.querySelectorAll ) {
  element = parent.querySelectorAll('.project_username')[0];

// Else, if getElementsByClassName is supported, use it.
} else if ( parent.getElementsByClassName ) {
  element = parent.getElementsByClassName('project_username')[0];

// Else, roll up our sleeves, let's do this the hard way
} else {
  var spans = parent.getElementsByTagName("span"), 
      spani = spans.length;
  while ( spani-- ) {
    if ( spans[spani].className === "project_username" ) {
      element = spans[spani];
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

#### The Brevity of Using Great Tools

Or you could use something like jQuery to reduce your frustration:

```
var $element = $(".project_username");
```

Comment: Note that you can(and probably do) have a huge number of `<span>` in the page, It would be better practice the reduce the selection with the span parent.

Comment: @gdoron You're right; I was trying intentionally leaving that out to keep the code down, but realized it doesn't really add too much bloat, so I've added it back in.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var project_username = document.getElementById('project_user').getElementsByClassName('project_username')[0].innerHTML;
alert(project_username);
```

Or using jQuery it is much easier:

```
var project_username = $('.project_username');
alert(project_username);
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName()` is not cross browser compatible like IE 8 doesn't support it, you may have to write your own *getElementsByClassName()* where it is not supported.

Here is an alternate:

```
var projUser = document.getElementById('project_user');
var projUsername = projUser.getElementsByTagName('span')[0]; // If you need 1st span's content
var userame = projUsername.innerHTML;
```

You can also write it in one line.

```
var userame = document.getElementById('project_user').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
```