# ContextMenu in IE to get the current opened browser url

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, contextmenu

I have created an option in IE context menu, so when I open IE, and right click in the window, the added menu is available. Now what I want to do is, I want to get the url of current window. So suppose I open www.facebook.com, then I right click, and choose the additional menu, I want to get the location as www.facebook.com.

How to do this using Javascript? I tried using:

```
  alert(window.location.href);
```

However, the location is the location of my test.html file: which has this script:

```
<html>
alert(window.location.href);
</html>
```

Comment: An option in the contextmenu ..? In the native contextmenu, or something on your web page, or is this a plug-in ...? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: context menu in IE. to execute file from regedit.

Answer (score 1):

In the htm file, you want to access the `external.menuArguments` property to access the context from the page you started on (i.e. any selection data or the original dom document object). This should get you the href you're looking for:

```
external.menuArguments.document.href
```

Bonus, for selected text in IE 11:

```
external.menuArguments.document.getSelection().toString()
```

Edit: also, don't forget to wrap your javascript in a `<script></script>` tag!