# How to check if any div has inner div having specific class say 'xyz' using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="abc">
  <a><img></a>
  <h4></h4>
  <div class="xyz">
    <a href="google.com">Hello</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

in above html code how do i check whether `div` having class `abc` has `div` having class `xyz`.

Comment: just curious, why don't to you use jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('div.abc div.xyz');
if (1 == list.length) {
    alert("found");
}
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3xQ5X/

Comment: Shouldn't this be `1 <= list.length`, `0 < list.length` or just `if (list.length)` as classes can be non-unique? You may also want to mention the `>` operator for selectors, if OP wants direct children.

Comment: The question is not clear about that. I had it first like you suggested. But the question says: "*whether div having class abc has div having class xyz*" which could be interpreted as "*has one div with class `xyz`*". But of course it can be adjusted if it's valid to have more than one of those `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$("div.abc").has("div.xyz");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:
Get your parent div an id like abc.

```
var v =  document.getElementById('abc');
for(var i in v.children)
{
 if( v.children[i].nodeName == 'DIV')//this will tell if the parent div has children divs
 {
  console.log(v.children[i].className == 'xyz');//this will be true if the child div has a class named xyz.
 }
}
```

Also remember to modify this script according to your requirement. I mean you can give an specific class in place of id to the divs you want to traverse. To select all the divs containing some specific class, use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149522/selecting-a-div-by-classname)'s function.

Answer (score 0):

This script will do the needful.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    if($("div.abc").children('div').hasClass("xyz"))
    {
        alert("found");
    }

});
</script>
```