# reloading a td value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am not really an expert in javascript, but I tried many things and I cant get it working. I need to reload a value in td tag which has only class, my html code is like this

```
<tr>
<td class="scFormPopupLeft"></td>
<td class="scFormPopupContent">test info at</td>
<td class="scFormPopupRight"></td>
</tr>
```

so what i would like to do is to reload a `td` tag with new value, so there should be something else instead of the `test info at` message, but I can't get it shown. any help would be appreciated.

Thanks on this solution:

```
document.querySelector(".scFormPopupContent").textContent = "Whatever you like"
```

Comment: What do you mean "reload" ? Grab the new info from the server?

Comment: something like when i use OnClick event that the td tag is reloaded, I have the same thing for the form, like this document.getElementById('nmsc_iframe_liga_app_grid_docs').contentWindow.location.reload(); and now I would need something similar for the td

Comment: Can you please at least show code of what you have recently tried that seems not to work?

Comment: At the time of reload `document.querySelector(".scFormPopupContent").textContent = "Whatever you like"`

Answer (score 0):

if using jquery, not just the DOM use..

```
$(".scFormPopupContent").html('new content...');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want pure JS without jQuery, you can to do it like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149522/selecting-a-div-by-classname/5149557#5149557)):

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName) {

    document.getElementsByClassName = function (classname) {
        var elArray = [];

        var tmp = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

        var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\s)" + classname + "(\\s|$)");
        for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {

            if (regex.test(tmp[i].className)) {
                elArray.push(tmp[i]);
            }
        }

        return elArray;

    };
}

document.getElementsByClassName('scFormPopupContent')[0].innerHTML = 'replaced';
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyYLW/) demo. Note that `getElementsByClassName` will return array of all elements matching your class name, so you have to use index to use just one or loop to go through all of them.

**EDIT:** With jQuery, it will be just:

```
$('td.scFormPopupContent').text('replaced');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("scFormPopupContent")[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "your content value";
```

Other option is set an ID for your td tag:

```
<td class="scFormPopupContent" id="my_td">test info at</td>
```

And then in your JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementsById("scFormPopupContent")[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "your content value";
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it [like this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AXdtH/1146/)

```
function ReplaceContentInTD(matchClass, content) {

    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

    for (i in elems) {
        if ((" " + elems[i].className + " ").indexOf(" " + matchClass + " ") > -1) {
            elems[i].innerHTML = content;
        }
    }
}

ReplaceContentInTD("scFormPopupContent", "my new value");
```